# Почему URL получается без прокси?

Tags: java, url, proxy

Выполняю

```
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("proxy.****.ru", 3128));
    URLConnection urlConnection = new URL(url_).openConnection(proxy);
    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(80000);
    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(80000);
    URL url = urlConnection.getURL();
```

а в результате переменная url получается без прокси. и дальше она передается без прокси. 
В чем проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`vSphere API` требует особый путь к `sdk`. Просто указав сервер `server.com` не получится, нужно добавить  `server.com/sdk`

Comment: Простите, но как этот ответ связан с вопросом?

Comment: кто знает vijava, тот поймет. проблема в этом была. а выдает совсем другое

Comment: @SeniorAutomator разясните что это и зачем?

Comment: @FORTRAN если коротко, то нужно обратиться  к api, который находится в /skd. а я обращался только по адресу,
vijava - библиотека для управления виртуальной инфраструктурой Vmware vSphere. Хоть и проголосовали на удаление вопроса, хочу оставить, так как поможет другим людям

Comment: а каково практичиское пименения этой технологии?

Answer (score 1):

Потому что URL - это строка. У нее нет никаких свойств, которые бы не зависели от ее текстового представления. А поскольку имя прокси-сервера нигде внутри URL не записывается - то и вы видите то что видите.

Тут впору задавать другой вопрос - нафига там вообще где-то есть поле proxy. Скорее всего, кто-то подошел к программированию "методом чайника".

Comment: нет. проблема не в этом